# Computing the F-ratio under null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, experiment-design, inference, f-distribution

Statistical model for a Completely Randomized Design:

$$y_{ij}=\mu+\tau_{i}+\epsilon_{ij}\quad i=1,2,\ldots,a; 
j=1,2,\ldots,n$$

where,

$y_{ij}$ is the $j$th observation of $i$th treatment effect

$\mu$ is the overall mean

$\tau_{i}$ is the $i$th treatment effect

$\epsilon_{ij}$ random error term and $\epsilon_{ij}\sim NID(0,\sigma^2)$

For testing the hypothesis of no difference in treatment means

$$H_0:\tau_1=\tau_2=\ldots=\tau_a = 0 \quad vs.\quad H_1:\tau_i\ne 0\quad \text{for some } i.$$

Under `null` hypothesis , the ratio
$$F=\frac{\frac{SS_{treatments}}{a-1}}{\frac{SS_{error}}{N-a}}$$
is distributed as F with $a-1$ and $N-a$ degrees of freedom .

- My question is: Why do i have to compute the F-ratio under `null` hypothesis,
  why do not  under `alternative` hypothesis ?

Comment: Which alternative will you compute it under?

Comment: Exactly what @Glen_b said. There are literally, not figuratively, an infinite number of alternative hypotheses to consider.

Comment: In a linear models course you would find the *distribution* of $F$ under the alternative.  (It's a noncentral $F$ distribution, if you care.)  Now, as to why not: the goal of statistical hypothesis testing is determine if the *null* hypothesis is consistent with the observed data.  The null occupies a privileged position in this schema and so is used as a standard of comparison.

Comment: Leaf - please check you're happy with Dennis' edit. If not you can edit again, but keep his comments on the reasons for the edit in mind.

Comment: My teacher said something like that(I can not recall it exactly):"we need the F-ratio under null hypothesis so that both numerator and denominator have variance $\sigma^2$, which cancels out. If we don't compute the F-ratio under null hypothesis, then the numerator has variance more than $\sigma^2$.Something about $\frac{SS_{treatments}}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{a-1}$ and Cochran theorem." I couldn't able to visualize.

Comment: @Dennis Can you please make me understand "Why $$H_0:\tau_1=\tau_2=\ldots=\tau_a = 0 \quad vs.\quad H_1:\tau_i\ne 0\quad \text{for some } i.$$ is more appropriate than $$H_0:\tau_1=\tau_2=\ldots=\tau_a  \quad vs.\quad H_1:\tau_i\ne \tau_j\quad \text{for some } i\ne j.$$ "

Comment: @ Leaf:  Because if $\tau$ is some constant other than $0$, the value is not identifiable.  It could (and should) be in $\mu$.  I thought seriously about changing your model to a means model $Y_{i,j} = \mu_i + \epsilon_{i,j}$ rather than the effects model you presented.  I decided that did more violence to your writing than modifying the hypotheses.  Effects models are trying to fit $a+1$ mean parameters with $a$ sufficient statistics.  They don't fit without an arbitrary external constraint.